# Get permissions for a Facebook Event's Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm integrating Facebook Event walls on my site using the JS API.

Some events have "open" Walls (in that any logged-in user can post to them), some have Walls that will only accept posts after a user RSVPs, and others have their Wall turned off completely.

Is there a way to determine which is the current setting so I can hide the comment box when appropriate? The documentation does not seem to suggest I can:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it dose, if you open link in documentation, a example of graph call, you get this json which cointains privacy inforamtion:

```
{
.....
privacy: "OPEN"
updated_time: "2010-04-13T15:29:40+0000"
}
```

Comment: No, that's the privacy of the Event itself, not the Event's Wall.